# Выборка максимального значения из базы и одновременно другого поля

Tags: mysql, sql

Приветствую. Имеется база товаров, в ней есть поля `price` и `price_currency`.
Из базы выбирается максимально значение цены `MAX(price)` Как для этого значения выбрать соответствующее `price_currency` в том же запросе?

**UPD:** Второй запрос делать нежелательно, так как сильно громоздкий запрос с джоинами и большим where.

Comment: `Select price_currency from table where price = (Select MAX(price) from table)`  ?

Comment: вопрос в том как сделать это в одном запросе. Там добавляется еще куча условий в where когда выбирается макс значение, поэтому не хотелось бы делать второй запрос

Comment: Ну так может стоило привести полное описание проблемы со всем, что у вас есть и что нужно? Потому, что в текущем его виде мой комментарий решает вашу проблему полностью......... и как бы то ни было, что мешает добавить в условие `.... and price = (Select MAX(price) from table)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
SELECT other_field, max_field FROM table ORDER BY max_field DESC LIMIT 1
```

Заказываете сортировку по полю, которое должно быть максимальным, в обратном порядке. И с помощью `limit` получаете только одну запись (как раз искомую).
Если поле может быть null, то можно сделать `ORDER BY max_field DESC NULLS LAST`

По заявкам телезрителей.
Что делать, когда товаров с максимальной ценой не один?
Самый простой вариант - игнорировать всех, кроме одного первого попавшегося:)
Но если игнорировать по каким-то причинам невозможно, то попробуйте запрос с под-запросами.
Такой:

```
SELECT other_field, max_field
  FROM table t
  JOIN (SELECT MAX(max_field) max FROM table) m ON m.max = t.max_field
```

Или такой:

```
SELECT other_field, max_field
  FROM table
 WHERE max_field = (SELECT MAX(max_field) FROM table)
```

Не знаю придумали ли что-либо ещё для упрощения задачи.

Comment: А если товаров с максимальной ценой не одна штука?

Comment: `По заявкам телезрителей` ...... тут JOIN и ПОДЗАПРОС, которые ТС просил не делать....т.к. цитата `так как сильно громоздкий запрос с джоинами и большим where.`.... и от которых он отказался, после того как я написал свой комментарий))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Вот именно! Одним джоином меньше, одним больше. Какая разница? Проиндексирует по полю и максимум быстро отыщется. Будет привередничать - получит сами знаете что.

Comment: В принципе первый вариант должен подойти, цены указаны в старых белорусских рублях и долларах, поэтому разница в цифрах там огромная, так что два максимальных числа вряд ли попадут с разными валютами

Answer (score 2):

```
select max(price) as price,
       substr(max(concat(lpad(price,10,'0'),price_currency)),11) as price_currency
  from table
```

В lpad указать число символов дополнения большее, чем может быть в поле price. При желании запрос можно делать любой сложности и так же использовать gorup by.