# Обойтись одним запросом sql

Tags: sql, mysqli

Есть таблица служащие и департаменты. Понятно, что служащий работает в каком-то департаменте. Но момент в том, что он может работать сперва в одном департаменте, потом другом и т.д.

Имеем третью таблицу, в которой хранится, где работал/работает сотрудник. Соответственно, там есть колонки: id сотрудника, id департамента и две даты - с какой по какую он работал/работает в данном департаменте.

Хочу получить по всем сотрудниками - в каком департаменте и с какой даты он работает.

Я всё это взял с тестовой БД mysql и там они делают это в два запроса:

1) сперва выбирают из таблицы max(начальная дата) и группируют по id сотрудника и пихают это всё во временную таблицу

2) а потом делают join полученной таблицы с таблицей департамента, чтобы получить последнее место работы (департамент для каждого сотрудника).

Но разве это не слишком сложно?

Саму процедуру можно посмотреть [здесь](https://github.com/datacharmer/test_db/blob/6c60bc6b4a49af6aff1b8baea6ed4e4621fee06e/objects.sql) (show_departments)

Comment: Можно сразу сделать join двух запросов. Наверное, у них обучающие цели (показать временные таблицы).

Comment: А, наверно, вы правы.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/545054 например. вопросов как найти максимальные тут достаточно, поищите. Или вот http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/496515  тут я даю альтернативные подходы к решению для MySQL