# Не могу сделать ORDER BY перед GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

Подскажите почему два запроса выдают разные результаты?

1-ый запрос:

```
SELECT date, text, topic_id 
FROM forum_msgs 
ORDER BY topic_id,date DESC
```

и 2-ой запрос:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT date, text, topic_id 
      FROM forum_msgs 
      ORDER BY topic_id,date DESC
    ) t1
```

2-ой запрос выдаёт неотсортированную таблицу и поэтому запрос, который приведен ниже уже не имеет смысла.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT date, text, topic_id 
      FROM forum_msgs 
      ORDER BY topic_id,date DESC
    ) t1 
GROUP BY topic_id
```

Comment: потому что отсортирована только результирующая таблица вложенного запроса. Внешний select выбирает из этой "таблицы"  и честно говоря не знаю по какому принципу сортирует!

Comment: В запросе GROUP BY всегда предшествует ORDER BY. Если не сложно опишите, какую задачу решаете? Чего хотите добиться? Возможно есть другие способы.

Comment: `GROUP BY` не умеет работать с заранее отсортированными данными, он их сам сортирует так как сочтет нужным. Вы видимо когда пишите `select *` и делая `group by` ожидаете, что он вернет для каждой группы какое то определенное значение какого то определенного поля. НО какое значение он даст не определено, не думайте, что он даст например первое значение. он имеет право дать произвольное. кроме того во многих версиях MySQL уже по умолчанию запрещено использовать в запросах с group by колонки без агрегатных функций.

Comment: Задача простая..для каждого topic_id найти последнюю запись(по дате)

Comment: Посмотрите вот эти вопросы: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/496515/ и http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/545054/   и плюс к этому `select * from table where (topic_id, date) IN(select topic_id, max(date) from table group by topic_id)`

Comment: а банально вот так `SELECT *, MAX(\`date\`) AS \`max_date\` FROM forum_msgs GROUP BY topic_id` нельзя?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Не, ему нужна последняя запись, а не только дата. Осталось решить дублем какого из вопросов объявлять этот

Comment: А, ясненько..))

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо Mike - подсказал то что и было нужно. Итоговый запрос конечно немного сложнее, но основа легла на ура.

```
SELECT t1.parent_id, t1.id id,
                   t1.name,
                   t2.*
            FROM forum_dirs t1 LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT 
                    forum_topics.title, 
                    forum_topics.dir_id,
                    forum_topics.id topic_id, 
                    forum_topics.date topic_date,
                    forum_topics.user_id topic_user_id, 
                    users.logo topic_user_logo,
                    users.name topic_user_name, 
                    users.login topic_user_login,
                    t3.*
                FROM forum_topics LEFT JOIN users ON users.id=forum_topics.user_id 
                LEFT JOIN (
                    SELECT 
                        forum_msgs.text, 
                        forum_msgs.user_id msg_user_id,
                        forum_msgs.date msg_date,
                        forum_msgs.topic_id msg_topic_id,
                        users.logo msg_user_logo,
                        users.name msg_user_name, 
                        users.login msg_user_login 
                    FROM forum_msgs 
                    LEFT JOIN users ON users.id=forum_msgs.user_id 
                    WHERE (topic_id, date) IN (SELECT topic_id, max(date) FROM forum_msgs GROUP BY topic_id)
                ) t3 ON t3.msg_topic_id=forum_topics.id
                WHERE (dir_id, date) IN (SELECT dir_id, max(date) FROM forum_topics GROUP BY dir_id)
            ) t2 ON t2.dir_id=t1.id
```

Answer (score -1):

Наверное потому, что во втором случае вы делаете выборку из выборки. выборка идет опять в том порядке, как удобно оптимизатору.
А почему не использовать group by в том же выражении, что и order by? Они вполне могут сосуществовать в одной выборке.

Comment: В одном запросе он вначале сделает Group by, как ему удобно, а уже потом отсортирует то что получилось, а надо в обратном порядке. Хотя задача элементарная - выбрать последнюю запись в каждом topic_id по последней дате, а не так как они лежат в таблице. :(