# JOIN, LIMIT и COUNT()

Tags: sql, join, limit

Есть две таблицы:

```
1. album:
    - id;
    - title;
    - timeCreated;

2. photo:
    - id;
    - path;
    - thumb;
    - albumId;
```

В каждом альбоме, естественно, несколько фотографий. Так вот, нужно выбрать все альбомы, присоединить к ним `photo.thumb` где `photo.id` минимален, а затем подсчитать количество фотографий в альбоме.
Вот мой запрос:

```
SELECT album.*, photo.thumb as thumb, COUNT(photo.id) as count FROM album
LEFT JOIN photo ON photo.id =
(SELECT photo.id FROM photo WHERE photo.albumId = album.id LIMIT 1)
GROUP BY album.id
```

Проблема в том что `count = 1`, т.к. в `join'e` стоит `limit 1` (для того, чтобы в качестве `thumb` выбрать одну фотку). Как можно изменить запрос, чтобы `count` выдавал правильное количество?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так как вы в подзапросе не указывали сортировки, вероятно не имеет значения какая именно фотография будет получена. По этому ей вполне может быть фотография с минимальным thumb.

```
SELECT album.*, min(photo.thumb) as thumb, COUNT(photo.id) as count
  FROM album
  LEFT JOIN photo ON photo.albumId = album.id
 GROUP BY album.id
```

Comment: Запрос рабочий, спасибо. Непонятно только, как выбирается min(photo.thumb), если в поле thumb хранится путь к первью картинки вида upload/albums/album_598c1dcbdac5e3.37721142/photo_...

Comment: @ДенисСелюков По правилам сортировки строк выбирается. происходит посимвольное сравнение слева на право, первый же различный у строк символ проверяется на больше/меньше, следующие за ним символы значения не имеют. Если нужна какая то конкретная запись, можно воспользоваться трюком с сортировкой в сцепке с другим полем, как тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/545072/194569