# Почему не работает LIMIT SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Здравствуйте, почему-то этот код циклит лишь первую запись:

```
    $page = $_GET['page'];
    $result00 = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user WHERE pro = 1");
    $temp = mysqli_fetch_array($result00);
    $num = 1;
    $posts = $temp[0];
    $total = (($posts - 1) / $num) + 1;
    $total =  intval($total);
    $page = intval($page);
    if(empty($page) or $page < 0) $page = 1;
    if($page > $total) $page = $total;
    $start = $page * $num - $num;   

    $result = mysqli_query($connect, "
        SELECT user.name, user.surname, photo.image
        FROM user
        INNER JOIN photo
        ON user.id = photo.user
        ORDER BY photo.id
        LIMIT $start, $num;
    ");


    while ( $postrow[] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) )
```

Не работает правильно если я связываю 2 таблицы, вот если только с одной работает правильно, пример

```
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM user ORDER BY id LIMIT $start, $num");
```

Comment: в таблице photo точно больше одной записи?

Comment: @ГерманБорисов да

Comment: Вероятно в таблице photo более одной записи для каждого пользователя и в итоге у вас запрос возвращает больше записей, чем в таблице пользователей. тогда непонятно почему вы рассчитываете лимиты исходя только из количества пользователей, а не фотографий

Comment: @Mike да, Вы правы несколько записей для каждого пользователя, просто мне нужно брать в цикл первую фотографию, которую загрузил пользователь (выбираю это по id)

Comment: @Mike Можно, как-то по другому сделать, что мне нужно ?

Comment: значит вам надо добиться что бы запрос возвращал только эти первые фотографии. либо подклеить какой нибудь подзапрос, который вернет для каждого пользователя id "первой" фотографии и соответственно выбирать только эти фото. Или что то в этом роде сделать https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/545054/

Comment: Покажите остаток кода, у меня подозрение, что вы просто не всё выводите.