# Вычисление строки с минимальной ценой

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица в БД: `mod_id, mod_price, mod_parent,mod_percent`.

Мне нужно получить `mod_id` минимальной цены с учетом процента.

Как это сделать грамотно? Цену считаю в запросе

```
MIN(m.mod_price - (m.mod_price*m.mod_percent/100))
```

Comment: `select mod_id from tab .... order by (m.mod_price - (m.mod_price*m.mod_percent/100)) limit 1`

Comment: Гениально! И очень дешево по сравнению с вложенными запросами для 1М записей в БД :)))

Comment: Если цена **уже** считается в запросе, то можно просто `ORDER BY x LIMIT 1`, где x - порядковый номер столбца (начиная с единицы) с этой ценой в выходном наборе. Правда, надо будет следить за корректностью этого номера, изменяя запрос...

Comment: @php-mvc Ну сортировка миллиона строк то же не самая быстрая операция. min возможно все таки быстрее, по идее ему не надо хранить все строки, а достаточно пару сверять... Это надо проверять. Если min быстрее то можно еще пойти таким путем: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/545072/194569

Comment: Вместо номера столбца стоит использовать alias