# mysql - группировка одного поля по значению другого поля

Tags: mysql, sql, запрос

Добрый день, помогите с mysql.
запрос - нужно вывести одну таблицу, например
field1 значения (100, 200, 300, 300, 400) field2 значения (1, 2, 1, 2, 2)

если в результате запроса в одном из полей (field1) одинаковые значения, нужно взять ту строку, в которой значение другого поля больше (field2) можете просто привести пример, как это написать, в общих чертах?

прим. вывод должен быть 100/1, 200/2, 300/2, 400/2

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/545072/194569

Answer (score -1):

Сам решил свой вопрос:

```
select 
      t1.time
    , t2.true_status
    , t1.name 
from table1 as t1
join (
    select 
          time
        , name
        , max(status) true_status 
    from table1
    group by time
) t2 on t2.time = t1.time AND t1.name = t2.name
group by time
```

Comment: хм. при том, что в ссылке, что я давал выше такое решение так же присутствует ...

Comment: вернее похожее, ваше решение не гарантирует правильного результата. потому что подзапрос при group by time может дать произвольный name, а не тот что относится именно к записи с максимальным статусом