# Неправильый вывод customer_id MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, inner-join

Исходные данные:
Есть несколько таблиц:
1. Основные:
developers
teams
projects
companies
customers
2. Таблицы, которые связывают основные:
devInTeam
projectsFromTheCompanies
projectsFromTheCustomers
customersOfCompanies

Я пытаюсь написать запрос, который выведет клиента, который приносит меньше всего прибыли для каждой из компаний. Вот он:

```
SELECT customer_id,
       company_id,
       min(profit) AS minprofit
FROM customersOfCompanies
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT customer_id,
          sum(cost) AS profit
   FROM
     (SELECT *
      FROM projects
      INNER JOIN projectsFromTheCustmer USING(project_id)) AS temporarytable
   GROUP BY customer_id) AS mytemptable USING(customer_id)
GROUP BY company_id;
```

Ошибка в выводе такая: неправильный customer_id если выводить просто profit, то минимальному соответствует другой customer_id. Что не так? Прошу прощения за левые alias, лень было придумывать нормальные. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: а группировать по нему не хотите?

Comment: 1. внимательно прочитайте это https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/599772/194569  там ответ на вопрос "почему customer другой". 2. "что делать ?", что то из этого: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/496515/194569 или https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/545054/194569

Comment: Mike, спасибо я на шаг ближе к решению проблемы. Я так понял что мой запрос выбирает минимальный профит у каждой из компаний и просто подставляет в строку первый попавшийся customer_id. Я пробовал не использовать min() а  отсортировать по возрастанию, но   результат всё равно неверный получается, точно так же customer_id первый попавшийся.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно сначала найти суммы по компании и кастомеру. А потом выбрать Строки со значениями = min из этих сумм по компании (джоин сумм по компаниям с минимальными суммами по компаниям)

Сделать лучше через обобщенные табличные выражения?

WITH SS (customer_id, compani_id, profit)
AS
(
SELECT customer_id, compani_id, sum(cost) AS profit
   FROM
     (SELECT *
      FROM projects
      INNER JOIN projectsFromTheCustmer USING(project_id)) AS temporarytable
      GROUP BY customer_id)
GROUP BY company_id, customer_id
)

SELECT customer_id, Compani_id, profit
FROM ss
INNER JOIN (SELECT compani_id, min(profit) FROM ss GROUP BY compani_id) AS Temp1 using(compani_id)

после последнего inner join могут быть синтаксические ошибки (негде сейчас проверить), но, надеюсь суть понятна.