# SQL запрос сам на себя, поиск ближайшего значения

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица продления длительности логинов пользователей:

```
id,login,date_prolong(дата когда продлили),date_finished (дата когда заканчивался логин),time_added (время на сколько продлили)
```

Задача отчета - в период от даты 1 до даты 2 (смотрим на дату окончания логина) выбрать какие логины продлялись, какие нет, и на сколько.

Как пытаюсь решить:

```
SELECT * FROM stb_prolong LEFT JOIN 
( SELECT  date_prolong as last_prolong_date, date_finished as date_ended, p.login, time_added as this_prolong_time_added  FROM stb_prolong p
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT login , min(abs(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_prolong)-UNIX_TIMESTAMP( stb_prolong.date_finished )) ) as diff 
        FROM stb_prolong 
        GROUP BY(login)
        ) mx ON mx.login=p.login AND mx.diff = (abs(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(p.date_prolong)-UNIX_TIMESTAMP( stb_prolong.date_finished )) ) 
GROUP BY(login)
) a ON a.login =stb_prolong.login 

WHERE date_finished >'2018-12-01' AND date_finished < '2018-12-31'
```

Т.е. я для для каждого логина пытаюсь найти строчку из той же таблицы с ближайшей к дате окончания логина датой продления, для чего сначала ищу ближайшую дату

```
min(abs(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_prolong)-UNIX_TIMESTAMP( stb_prolong.date_finished )) )
```

еще одним подзапросом.

Но во вложенных подзапросах у меня поля stb_prolong.date_finished нет, что логично. Как бы его туда "протащить"?. Ну или вообще буду раз если подскажете вообще новый подход к решению.. И да, это mySQL.

Comment: *выбрать какие логины продлялись, какие нет*  Т.е. вывести ВСЕ логины? *в период от даты 1 до даты 2 (смотрим на дату окончания логина) выбрать какие логины продлялись* Что есть продлялись "в период"? только когда date_prolong попадает в этот период? или когда период продления и заданный период пересекаются? *это mySQL* А версия какая?

Comment: в период от даты до даты это вот: WHERE date_finished >'2018-12-01' AND date_finished < '2018-12-31'. Мне нужны все логины которые заканчиались в этот период и посмотреть продлялись они или нет и когда и на сколько продлялись.

Comment: Увы, количество понимания не увеличилось. Попробуйте откорректировать вопрос и более подробно расписать задачу, с примерами входных данных и желаемого результата.

Comment: И всё же укажите версию сервера - на 5+ и на 8+ задача будет решаться совершенно по-разному. И ещё - Вы хотите ВСЕ логины. Однако гарантируете ли Вы, что любой логин присутствует в ЭТОЙ таблице? что если логин ни разу не продлялся?

Comment: И ещё вопрос. Что нужно вывести, если некий логин продлялся более одного раза: 1) только в заданный период 2) в заданный период и после него.

Comment: Попробую по-другому рассказать. С конца - логины присутствуют все, в момент создания тут тоже есть запись. Эта таблица по сути лог продления логинов. 2 даты. Дата когда продлили и дата до которой продлили (когда закончится). Нужно для всех логинов которые закончились в декабре вывести когда их  последний раз продляли.

Comment: А может тогда просто взять все логины у которых дата окончания декабрь, сгруппировать по логину и взять максимальную дату продления ?

Comment: ну вот только надо бы не максимальную а дату, ближайшую к дате окончания, т.к. это может быть "декабрь прошлого года"...

Comment: т.е. вместо MAX(date_prolong) я пытаюсь как-то так min(abs(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_prolong)-UNIX_TIMESTAMP( stb_prolong.date_finished )) ) , но вот даты окончания от основного запроса в подзапросах "не видно"..

Comment: *это может быть "декабрь прошлого года"* Во WHERE отбирается вполне определённый год - так что никакой "прошлый год" в выборку не попадает.

Comment: А почему максимальная дата это не ближайшая к дате окончания ? Если продление происходит после окончания предыдущего, то максимальная дата продления должна быть и ближайшей к максимальной дате окончания

Comment: но если все таки это так как вы считаете и вот тот min(abs) в принципе дает именно нужную запись, то можно прицепить поле с датой к этому минимуму, что бы его достать, как нибудь так https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/545072/194569