# LEFT JOIN вставить из другой таблицы по наибольшему id

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, запрос

У меня есть вот такой код.

```
SELECT
    route.cg_id,
    msg.text AS `text`,
    MAX(msg.date) AS `lastvisit`,
    contragents.*
FROM
    `route`
LEFT JOIN contragents ON route.cg_id = contragents.id
LEFT JOIN msg ON route.cg_id = msg.whom AND msg.type = 1
WHERE
    `userid` = 7 AND route.guid = "PlMFQR" OR route.cg_id IS NULL
GROUP BY
    `cg_id`
ORDER BY
    `id`
DESC
```

Он подставляет из таблицы msg последнюю дату, и первый найденный подходящий msg.text, но мне нужно не первый, а последний msg.text 
Подскажите как можно это поправить

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/545072/194569